# Most Efficient Way to Retrieve Texture Pixel Data?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es-2.0, opengl-es-3.0

I know Directx for Dx9 at least, has a texture object where you are able to get only a small portion of the texture to CPU accessible memory. It was a function called "LockRect" I believe. OpenGL has `glGetTexImage()` but it grabs the entire image and if the format isn't the same as the texture's then it is going to have to convert the entire texture into the new pixel format on top of transferring the entire texture. This function is also not in OpenGL ES. Framebuffers is another option but where I could potentially bind a framebuffer where a color attachment in connected to a texture. Then there is `glReadPixels` which reads from the framebuffer, so it should be reading from the texture. `glReadPixels` has limited pixel format options so a conversion is going to have to happen, but I can read the pixels I need (which is only 1 pixel). I haven't used this method but it seems like it is possible. If anyone can confirm the framebuffer method, that it is a working alternative. Then this method would also work for OpenGL ES 2+.

Are there any other methods? How efficient is the framebuffer method (if it works), does it end up having to convert the entire texture to the desired format before it reads the pixels or is it entirely implementation defined?

Edit: @**Nicol_Bolas** Please stop removing OpenGL from tags and adding OpenGL-ES, OpenGL-ES isn't applicable, OpenGL is. This is for OpenGL specifically but I would like it to be Open ES 2+ compatible if possible, though it doesn't have to be. If a OpenGL only solution is available then it is a consideration I will make if it is worth the trade off. Thank you.

Comment: they do that with u as well altering the question as they think it is better by force, bullies as they used to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note, I do not have that much experience with ES in particular, so there might be better ways to do this specifically in that context. The general gist applies in either plain OpenGL or ES, though.

---

First off, the most important performance consideration should be when you are doing the reading. If you request data from the video card while you are rendering, your program (the CPU end) will have to halt until the video card returns the data, which will slow rendering due to your inability to issue further render commands. As a general rule, you should always upload, render, download - do not mix any of these processes, it will impact speed immensely, and how much so can be very driver/hardware/OS dependent.

I suggest using `glReadPixels( )` at the end of your render cycle. I suspect the limitations on formats for that function are connected to limitations on framebuffer formats; besides, you really should be using 8 bit unsigned or floating point, [both of which are supported](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man32/html/glReadPixels.xhtml). If you have some fringe case not allowing any of those supported formats, you should explain what that is, as there may be a way to handle it specifically.

If you need the contents of the framebuffer at a specific point in rendering (rather than the end), create a second texture + framebuffer (again with the same format) to be an effective "backbuffer" and then copy from the target framebuffer to that texture. This occurs on the video card, so it does not impose the bus latency directly reading does. Here is something I wrote that does this operation:

```
glActiveTexture( GL_TEXTURE0 + unit );
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, backbufferTextureHandle );
glBindFramebuffer( GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, framebufferHandle );
glCopyTexSubImage2D(
        GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        0, // level
        0, 0, // offset
        0, 0, // x, y
        screenX, screenY );
glBindFramebuffer( GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, framebufferHandle );
```

Then when you want the data, bind the backbuffer to GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER and use `glReadPixels( )` on it.

Finally, you should keep in mind that a download of data will still halt the CPU end. If you download before displaying the framebuffer, you will put off displaying the image until after you can again execute commands, which might result in visible latency. As such, I suggest still using a non-default framebuffer even if you only care about the final buffer state, and ending your render cycle to the effect of:

(1.) Blit to the default framebuffer:

```
glBindFramebuffer( GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 0 ); // Default framebuffer
glBindFramebuffer( GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, framebufferHandle );
glBlitFramebuffer(
        0, 0, screenX, screenY,
        0, 0, screenX, screenY,
        GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT,
        GL_NEAREST );
```

(2.) Call whatever your swap buffers command may be in your given situation.

(3.) Your download call from the framebuffer (be it `glReadPixels( )` or something else).

As for the speed impact of the blit/texcopy operations, it's quite good on most modern hardware and I have not found it to have a noticeable impact even done 10+ times a frame, but if you are dealing with antiquated hardware, it might be worth a second thought.

Comment: I am trying to get a texture who's contents will not change once it is loaded from the disk into GPU memory. I don't need a specific format, but simply that using `glReadPixels()` will require some sort of computations if the formats don't match, being slower but not sure by how much. I only need to retrieve a single pixel so it shouldn't be too bad, in the worst case being a compressed format like DXT. It would save me some work though. The logical order is to get the pixel and use that pixel as input for rendering. There is also computations done with it along with multiple samples.

Comment: @user3901459 The amount of data doesn't really affect the speed; the bus latency is the main limiting factor, not bandwidth, so one pixel takes about the same time as a whole framebuffer. That said, if you only want data you are uploading, I think you're going about this wrong. Just keep whatever image array you initially pass to OpenGL. If you're loading a compressed format from disc that's a bit harder; I don't have any experience with texture compression, but presumably you can do that in software and cut out the GPU entirely.

Comment: At some point the bandwidth is going to influence it though right? For a really large texture as an example, grabbing the entire thing would make it slower? I guess it would depend on how long it takes relative to the latency. Keeping it all in memory wouldn't be the best either, if all else fails I'd have to but it would essentially double memory usage. Especially on a shared memory system like a mobile device. I guess could make some hybrid system that reads the texture and stores it in CPU memory, if it isn't used for a while then delete it. It would still need to be fast enough or it'd stu

Comment: @user3901459 Latency is the main factor. Video bandwidth is pretty good and usually you upload/download a lot without knowing it. It's waiting for the two-way commands to occur that is the main problem, especially since the GPU will have to wait for any queued commands to complete.

Comment: @user3901459 It doesn't actually double the memory usage because the CPU and video memory are different. So if you delete it after upload, the texture effectively occupies 0 normal system memory. Even where the actual physical memory comes from the same place, it's usually divided into fixed chunks, so you don't really lose anything. Downloading each frame to avoid keeping the data is really clunky and will probably introduce other problems that negate the benefit. However, I am speaking from the point of view of someone who does desktop OpenGL for video CARDS - so it might differ a bit.